# Ruby on Rails - link_to - quotes in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

This is what I want:

```
class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navMenuCollapse"
```

This is what I got:

```
class="\&quot;navbar-toggle\&quot; data-toggle = \&quot;collapse\&quot; data-target = \&quot;.navMenuCollapse\&quot;"
```

This is what I tried:

```
<%= link_to 'test', welcome_index_path, {:class => '\"navbar-toggle\" data-toggle = \"collapse\" data-target = \".navMenuCollapse\"'} %>
```

Is there any opportunity to get quotes in the class-tag ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: you don't need to escape " inside a string delimited by '

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to put a bunch of attributes **inside** the class value.  The :class option is just for setting the class attribute.

Comment: Yea. I also got it now. :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= link_to 'test', welcome_index_path, :class => 'navbar-toggle', :'data-toggle' => 'collapse', :'data-target' => '.navMenuCollapse' %>
```

Comment: @MarekLipka Possibly the comment they left on Saravanan's answer (unless another comment existed before, and is now deleted).

Comment: Thanks :] I should carefully read the Api next time. –  Ismoh 2 hours ago

Answer (score 6):

Try the below code:

```
<%= link_to 'test', welcome_index_path, class: 'navbar-toggle', data: {toggle: 'collapse', target: '.navMenuCollapse'} %>
```